# Maximo - Get current Workflow position using java code

Tags: java, maximo

I'm trying to read from the database my current location in the workflow from a java class (work order). 
From here `WFAssignmentSet wfassignment = (WFAssignmentSet) this.getMboSet("WFASSIGNMENT");` I can extract the nodeID, but it seems like a very general number, not the exact position.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join to WFNODE from WFASSIGNMENT using PROCESSNAME, PROCESSREV and NODEID, you can get the XCOORDINATE and YCOORDINATE.